# php loop foreach wrong output

Tags: php, laravel, loops

Im trying to sort my database based on extension in laravel, so I try using php pathinfo for it and mix it with looping, yet for some reason the variabel $ext_name didnt output the real extension for the file.

Here is my code:

```
$i = 0;
            $pdf_file = [];
            $docx_file = [];
            $pdf = 0;
            $docx = 0;
            foreach($files as $i => $the_file){
                $path_name[$i] = $the_file["file_path"];
                $ext_name[$i] = pathinfo($path_name[$i],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                if($ext_name[$i]="pdf"){
                    $pdf_file[$pdf]= $the_file["name"];
                }
                elseif($ext_name[$i]="docx"){
                    $docx_file[$docx]= $the_file["name"];
                }

                ++$i;
                ++$pdf;
                ++$docx;

            }
```

dd result for $path_name and $ext_name:

$path_name

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => ".........../storage/app/file_processing/blablabla.pdf"
  1 => ".........../storage/app/file_processing/blablabla.docx"
  2 => ".........../storage/app/file_processing/blablabla.pdf"
  3 => ".........../storage/app/file_processing/blablabla.pdf"
  4 => ".........../storage/app/file_processing/blablabla.docx"
]
```

$ext_name

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => "pdf"
  1 => "pdf"
  2 => "pdf"
  3 => "pdf"
  4 => "pdf"
]
```

I dont know how $ext_name output the same extension like that, where exactly that i do something wrong?

Comment: you are assigning the value not comparing it in your `if` statement

Comment: all equals are equal. some equals are more equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may cleanup your code a bit.

```
$pdf_file = [];
$docx_file = [];
$ext_name = [];

foreach($files as $key => $file){
  $ext_name[$key] = pathinfo($file["file_path"],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

  if($ext_name[$key] === "pdf"){
    $pdf_file[$key]= $file["name"];
  } elseif ($ext_name[$key] === "docx"){
    $docx_file[$key]= $file["name"];
  }
}

dd($pdf_file,$docx_file,$ext_name);
```

You should use `==` or `===` instead of `=`.

Also why this happen? because you assign the pdf to the `ext_name[$i]` so every iteration of the foreach the `ext_name[$i]` will ovewrite the `pdf` extension.

`=` is an assignment operator and `==` ond `===` is an equality operator

Comment: I highly appreciate your effort to not only fix and explain why its wrong, you also tidy up my code, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```php
if ($ext_name[$i] === "pdf") {
```

OR

```php
if ($ext_name[$i] == "pdf") {
```

BUT DON'T DO:

```php
if ($ext_name[$i] = "pdf") {
```

> **Note** that single equal-sign will always just set variable, even if it's written in if-statement.
>
> Same for your other line:
>
> ```php
> elseif($ext_name[$i]="docx"){
> ```